# Eclipse WTP, Axis 2 Web Service Client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to build a web service and a client for this service. I'm using Eclipse 3.5.1 with axis2-1.4.1. I'm facing a problem:

I created the web service via the web service wizard and the service shows up in the axis service list. If I porint to the wsdl - its generated.

Now when I'm trying to build the client, I choose the wsdl, the client project and take the next button, well at the client web service configuration everything is empty. There is nor service name, no port name. Am I facing a bug? Anyoneelse faced something like this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so let me sum up:

The eclipse wizard seems buggy yes. It didn't show anything after the first step. What I've done? I created my stubs from the command line and WSDL2Java. The produced code works.

This problem occus with axis2-1.5.1 too, so no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
You can use Eclipse Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 1

And Axis2-1.3. It creates the stub.

Comment: I'm using Juno and Axis2 1.6.2 and I'm getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Juno and Axis2 1.6.2 and I'm getting the same problem - the WTP wizard just doesn't work for me.

I downloaded the [Code Generator Wizard for Eclipse Plug-in](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html) and this produced the client code for me. Follow the link for more info on installation and use.